# Speed improvements of python object creation

Tags: python, performance, optimization, memory-management

This question is academic in nature and typically if I had these issues in the real world I'd probably do things differently. However I was curious about whether the speed at which python objects are created could be improved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

# boring class
class boring:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

def timefunc(f):
    def f_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print f.__name__, 'took', end - start, 'time'
        return result
    return f_timer

@timefunc
def standard_boring():
    for x in range(10000000):
        b = boring(1,2,3)
    del(b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    standard_boring()
```

On my machine this takes about 4 seconds. So curious what Python is doing I dug deeper using strace.

What I see is many tens of thousands of calls to brk e.g. -

```
brk(0xe35000)                           = 0xe35000
brk(0xe34000)                           = 0xe34000
brk(0xe33000)                           = 0xe33000
brk(0xe32000)                           = 0xe32000
brk(0xe31000)                           = 0xe31000
```

Man describes brk as

> brk() and sbrk() change  the  location  of  the  program  break,  which
>          defines  the end of the process's data segment (i.e., the program break
>          is the first location after the end of the uninitialized data segment).
>          Increasing the program break has the effect of allocating memory to the
>          process; decreasing the break deallocates memory.

Each call to this presumably some number of cycles, as such the very fact there are loads of calls to this makes me think this is what takes the time.

So is there a way to tell python "Yo, I'm going to be using lots of memory so allocate loads up front". Can I do anything like that? I know why you wouldn't want to, like I said this is academic.

I've experimented with slots, hypothesizing that if I use less memory then this should improve my speed by the very nature of reducing the reoccurring memory allocation requests. I found the results from this quite "lumpy".

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably should try a line-oriented profiler.  I'm not convinced that the brk()'s are the issue.  You may find that using __slots__ and/or Cython will help.

Comment: Which version of Python?  If Python 2, your `range(10000000)` will create a gigantic list of 10 million integers, which is far more of a memory burden than the rest of your program combined.  So if you're using Python 2, change `range` to `xrange` and report back ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters Python version 2.7.5. I'd overlooked the range/ xrange thing (I knew about it but was having brain freeze. It does indeed have an improvement taking it down to about 3.7 seconds. Not massive but reasonable.

Comment: I'm more interested in whether changing to `xrange` reduced the number of `brk` calls - your program uses a *tiny* amount of memory if the gigantic list is removed, because each `boring` instance is destroyed immediately after it's created (your `del(b)` doesn't really do anything).

Comment: @TimPeters the number of brk calls is really small now. With range the strace created file is about 60000 lines, with xrange its about 1000....

Comment: So you've learned two things:  creating 10 million int objects and storing them in a giant list accounted for the `brk` calls; and, the speed of `brk` has little to do with the time consumed regardless.  You're creating 10 million objects - how fast do you *expect* that to go?  That's a lot of objects.

Comment: @TimPeters You right, how fast do I expect it to go? I don't know but I was really curious whether there was any slack there, and there was.